# which numpy command could I use to subtract vectors with different dimensions many times?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

i have to write this function:
[image]
in which x is a vector with dimensions [150,2] and c is [N,2] (lets suppose N=20). From each component xi (i=1,2) I have to subtract the components of c in this way ([x11-c11,x12-c12])...([x11-cN1, x12-cN2])for all the 150 sample.
I've trasformed them in a way I have the same dimensions and I can subtract them, but the result of the function should be a vector. Maybe How can I write this in numpy?
Thank you
Ok, lets suppose x=(5,2) and c=(3,2)
[image]
this is what I have obtained transforming dimensions of the two arrays. the problem is that, I have to do this but with a iteration "for loop" because the exp function should give me as a result a vector. so I have to obtain a sort of matrix divided in N blocks.

Comment: So you are subtracting just from the first row of x? Can you add sample data for example for x shape (5,2) and c shape (3,2)?

Comment: I think you need another axis in x to account for the 20 values of the vector `c`: i.e. `x[:, None] - c` to give an array of shape `(150,20,2)`

Comment: iGian i have added an example :)

Comment: For the element 1,1 of the matrix you mean `(8-1)+(8-5)+(8-5)`? Anyway, it seems that the result is still a matrix having the same shape of x...

Comment: You probably need something like `(x[:,None,:] - c).reshape(-1,2)`. Without the reshape you have 150 blocks of `(N,2)` arrays, like `res[0,...]`.

Comment: Why should your `exp` function give an array with dimensions `(150,2)` when `c` has dimensions `(20,2)`?

Comment: oh ok, maybe I haven't explained my self as well I'm sorry. my problem is that even if c has dimension (20,2) I have to subtract from each of the 150 xi (i=1,2) the c (as I show in the example), and then to put in the function in the pictures. with N=20 I've done the subtraction because I've trasformed x and c in two vectors with dimensions (3000,2). but maybe it isn't what I have to do because the result of the first function I posted should be a vector not a scalar so maybe a need a for loop.

Comment: Sure, then the subtraction has dimensions `(150,20,2)`, and the argument to your exponential has dimensions `(150,20)` (after taking the norm of the `(150,20)` 2-dimensional vectors... or is this not right?

Comment: xnx yes, you're perfectly right but I do something wrong because the exponential doesn't give be a vector but a scalar. could you show me how would you do this? do you use a for loop?

Comment: @ggg I've posted an answer which i think does what you want, if the problem lies with the scalar vs vector problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand of the issue, the problem seems to be in the way you are calculating the vector norm, not in the subtraction. Using your example, but calculating `exp(-||x-c||)`, try:

```
x = np.linspace(8,17,10).reshape((5,2))
c = np.linspace(1,6,6).reshape((3,2))
sub = np.linalg.norm(x[:,None] - c, axis=-1)
np.exp(-sub)

array([[  5.02000299e-05,   8.49325705e-04,   1.43695961e-02],
       [  2.96711024e-06,   5.02000299e-05,   8.49325705e-04],
        [  1.75373266e-07,   2.96711024e-06,   5.02000299e-05],
        [  1.03655678e-08,   1.75373266e-07,   2.96711024e-06],
        [  6.12664624e-10,   1.03655678e-08,   1.75373266e-07]])

np.exp(-sub).shape
(5, 3)
```

[`numpy.linalg.norm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) will try to return some kind of matrix norm across all the dimensions of its input unless you tell it explicitly which axis represents the vector components.

Answer (score 0):

I I understand, try if this give the expected result, but there is still the problem that the result has the same shape of `x`:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
c = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)

c_col_sum = np.sum(c, axis=0)

for (h,k), value in np.ndenumerate(x):
  x[h,k] = c.shape[0] * x[h,k] - c_col_sum[k]
```

Initially `x` is:

```
[[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [4 5]
 [6 7]
 [8 9]]
```

And `c` is:

```
[[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [4 5]]
```

After the function `x` becomes:

```
[[-6 -6]
 [ 0  0]
 [ 6  6]
 [12 12]
 [18 18]]
```